# Android: Dynamically close the virtual keypad though code?

Tags: android, android-keypad

How can you dynamically close the virtual keypad through code?
All I want to do is close it when the user clicks an "Ok" button because it is not closing itself even though the button now has focus.

Comment: I'm sure if you goto ... I think it's Freenode IRC server, there's an android-dev channel that is EXTREMELY helpful.  I'm sure if you go in there SOMEONE will know exactly how to do this (if it's possible)

Comment: @ Crowe:
I went to freenode.net and I could not even figure out how it works.

Comment: It's an IRC server, you need a IRC client. You could probably use Mibbit (it's a free web-based client). Freenode should be one of the servers it lets you join, and then you need to join the android-dev channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question

Comment: Yes, it does. "You can force Android to hide the virtual keyboard using the InputMethodManager, calling hideSoftInputFromWindow, passing in the token of the window containing your edit field." That answers your question "How can you dynamically close the virtual keypad through code?".

Comment: "hide" != "close"
I will still need the keypad to open when I click again in another text field

Comment: I had to attach this to a button so that the keypad can keep reappearing the next time I entered a text box

Answer (score 3):

Hi i got one more solution to hide keyboard by :

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

Here pass HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY at the position of showFlag and 0 at the position of hiddenFlag.
It will forcefully close soft Keyboard.